# From string to pyqt object as variable

Tags: python, variables, pyqt

i have a lot of checkboxes (like 500) which state i want to save. Their names are like:
pr0, pr1, pr2 etc.

What i want to do is:

```
try:
    if self.ui.pr0.isChecked():
        pr0 = 1
    else:
        pr0 = 0
except:
    pr0 = 0
```

is there a way to put variable into line number 2?

```
list = []
for i in range(500):
    try:
        if self.ui.(variable).isChecked():
            pr = 1
        else:
            pr = 0
    except:
        pr = 0
    list.append(pr)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function from the standard library.

```
for i in range(500):
  var_name = "pr%i" % i
  var_value = getattr(self.ui, "pr%i" % i).isChecked()
  print "%s has value: %s" % (var_name, var_value)
```

Answer (score 2):

A more general way would be to use [`QObject.findChildren`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#findChildren) to dynamically get a list of all checkboxes.

```
checkboxes = self.ui.findChildren(QtGui.QCheckBox, QtCore.QRegExp(r'pr\d+'))
values = {}
for cb in checkboxes:
    values[cb.objectName()] = cb.isChecked()  
    # If you absolutely want to cast to int, though you shouldn't have to.
    # values[cb.objectName()] = int(cb.isChecked())
```

This will give you a dictionary with `Object Name: check value` for each checkbox.  You can then save the dictionary using json or pickle, and then restore it by iterating through it, using `findChildren` the same way.

```
for name, value in values.items():
    try:
        child = self.ui.findChildren(QtGui.QCheckBox, name)[0]
        child.setChecked(value)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```